# Configuring Vite with styled-jsx

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, tailwind-css, vite, postcss

I want to be able to add classes through styled-jsx which can be nested and have tailwind directives(@apply screen etc.). Right now it's working on imported css files.
Here's my Vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      babel: {
        parserOpts: {
          plugins: [
            "styled-jsx/babel",
            // {
            //   plugins: ["styled-jsx-plugin-postcss"],
            // },
          ],
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

As you see `plugins: ["styled-jsx-plugin-postcss"]` is commented, because it results in an error, but it's essential to use postcss settings.

If somebody interested, here's the postcss.config.cjs(for non Vite it's .js):

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'tailwindcss/nesting': 'postcss-nesting',
    'postcss-preset-env': {
      stage: 1
    },
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

Is there a way to configure it in Vite.js ( in Next.js it's trivial, so if someone wants to suggest this idea, just don't, it's about Vite!)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this implementation and everything seems to work like a charm

```
plugins: [
react({
  babel: {
    plugins: [
      ["styled-jsx/babel", { "plugins": ["styled-jsx-plugin-postcss"] }]
    ],
  }
}),
```

Comment: Hi buddy, looking for the same issue. Ive got the error
"No PostCSS Config found in:  path"
What is your postcss file or how should it looks?
I'm just looking for nested feature, what is the basic config to make this works

Comment: Check out this medium:
https://medium.com/@soniceran/using-styled-jsx-with-vite-and-react-cabf0d2ac10b

Comment: thanks, but finally  dropping this styled jsx thing that incurs in frequently config issues, and moving to just css modules, works perfect even with scss files, no extra config. just works